# How can I render an image_field from within hook_block_view?

Tags: blocks, media

I want to contain my custom content type's image field (cck) within a block. I define the block within hook_block_view:

```
function foxyidx_block_view($delta)
{
    $t = get_t();
    if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
    }
    switch($delta)
    {
        case 'foxyidx_images':
            $block['subject'] = '';
            $render_out = drupal_render($node->field_image);
            $block['content'] = <<<HTML
                {$render_out}
HTML;
            break;
```

If I were to render the image_field in a template I would use

```
print drupal_render($content['image_field']);
```

However, in the hook_block_view function I assume I need to use another function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a combination of [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) would do the trick:

```
$image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$image_view = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', array_shift($image_items));

$block['content'] = render($image_view);
```

Comment: You rock like a hurricane!

Comment: I modified this solution a little to handle multiple images in the image_field.

    $block['subject'] = '';
                $render_out = drupal_render($node->field_image);
                $image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
                $image_view = '';
                foreach($image_items as $image_item)
                {
                    $image_view .= render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image_item));
                }
    $block['content'] = $image_view;

Answer (score 2):

I modified this solution a little to handle multiple images in the image_field.

```
$block['subject'] = '';
            $render_out = drupal_render($node->field_image);
            $image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
            $image_view = '';
            foreach($image_items as $image_item)
            {
                $image_view .= render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image_item));
            }
$block['content'] = $image_view;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on drupal.org
It handles it in a different way.

http://drupal.org/node/154066